# how to pass a argument into another argument

Tags: tcl, argument-passing

I want to pass a Argument(key value) and inside the key may contain like key(value1 value2...) and value may be again value1(data1 data2 data2) the Format is shown below

```
proc find {args } {
    array set opt {-find "" }
    if {$opt(-find) == "?" } {
        ....
        puts "list of search items like google, msn"
    }
    if {$opt(-find) == "google" } {
        ....
        puts "...."
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the commands are

```
find -find ?
displayresults google, msn....

find -find google
displayresults gmail....

find -find google gmail
results username pw ...

find -find google gmail pw
displayresults ....
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `cmdline` package. Here is a little sample to get you started.

```
package require cmdline

proc find {args} {
    set flags {
        {server.arg ""   "Which server to search"}
    }

    array set options [cmdline::getoptions args $flags]

    if {$options(server) eq "google"} {
        puts "Search Google"
    } elseif {$options(server) eq "?"} {
        puts "Display Help"
    }
}

# Example usages    
find -server google one two three  ;# Case 1: $options(server)=="google"
find -server ?                     ;# Case 2: display help
find                               ;# Case 3: no -server flag
find -server "google msn" one two  ;# Case 3: $options(server)=="google msn"
```

## Discussion

- I call my flag `-server` instead of `-find`, which I thought is more meaningful.
- In the case when the user does not supply the `-server` flag, $options(server) is an empty string, `""`.
- The rest of the cases are self-explanatory.

Comment: Consider using `switch`, as that internally builds a hash table when choosing between literals.

Comment: Good idea. I used the if command because that is what the OP is comfortable using.

Comment: can i use HIERARCHICAL METHOD instead of package require cmdline?

Comment: What is **hierarchical method**?

Comment: how do i make the above function in hierarchical way or tree structure                                                                   find -server google    (...do something here)                                                                                                      find -server google.gmail                                                                                                     find -server google.gmail.username   suggest me without package